What is the best practice to bind and manipulate properties on a user control in a view model with ReactiveUI?
Coming from the web world you can easily create reusable components for a myriad of reasons. Many of these reusable components allow you to manipulate data properties given from set from a parent context. For example:
<IncrementButton startCount={1} title="My Title" />

When a user clicks the increment button count goes up by one.
But lets say I want the same component on Page 2, but I want the startCount to start at two with a different title:
<IncrementButton startCount={2} title="Hello World" />

In the second picture the count starts at two and increments to three on the first increment click.
What is the best practice to manipulate data with ReactiveUI/Avalonia when it is passed through a property:
Page One
<control:IncrementButton Count="1" Title="My Title" />
Page Two
<control:IncrementButton Count="2" Title="Hello World" />
Do I pass the control to the view model like this?
public class IncrementButton : UserControl
{
    public static readonly StyledProperty<int> CountProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.Register<MyButtonView, int>(nameof(Count));

    public int Count
    {
        get => GetValue(CountProperty);
        set => SetValue(CountProperty, value);
    }

    public IncrementButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set DataContext to a new instance of the ViewModel
        DataContext = new IncrementButtonViewModel(this); // Pass the control itself to the ViewModel
    }
}

How do I wire up the bindings to manipulate the starting count in the view model?

Do you need a view model for a small control like this?  MVVM is great but not suitable for all applications.  Small stand-alone controls are often best done with code behind.  MVVM is primarily for data presentation, i.e. the Model, if you aren't managing data, it's not really necessary.

@Tarazed it's not an actual project based component that I'm working with it's an example to understand property manipulation for reusable components

You expose a method: CountUp(). The consumer needs to see nothing else. Besides counting, you want a "Reset()" (to zero) probably. Initializing to other than 0, implies a "starting value" element: a TextBox; a NumericUpDown; and / or a Repeater.In the case of "viewing" the value, you need the equivalent of a "Binding" to a UI element; which get pulled in response to the actual "counter" generating "property change notifications" that other can subscribe to. The "starting value" gets pulled down when the "counter" first changes from "0" (which is the simpler case, IMO).

"Do I pass the control to the view model" - no, a view model has no knowledge of the view.

Avalonia Templated Controls is more suited for what you need

TemplatedControls are best used for generic controls that can be shared among various applications.

Create Templated Controls from avalonia templeates in controls Folder (just to aggregate all controls in single folder)
IncrementButton.axaml.cs
public class IncrementButton : TemplatedControl
{
    public static readonly StyledProperty<int> CountProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.Register<IncrementButton, int>(
            nameof(Count),
           defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public static readonly StyledProperty<string> TitleProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.Register<IncrementButton, string>(
            nameof(Title),
            defaultValue: "");

    public string Title
    {
        get => GetValue(TitleProperty);
        set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
    }
    public int Count
    {
        get => GetValue(CountProperty);
        set => SetValue(CountProperty, value);
    }


    protected override void OnApplyTemplate(TemplateAppliedEventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = e.NameScope.Find<Button>("Increment_btn");
        if (btn is not null)
            btn.Click += (s, e) => Count++;
    }
}

IncrementButton.axaml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="using:AvaloniaApplication5.Controls">
  
  <Design.PreviewWith>
    <StackPanel Width="400" Spacing="10">
          <controls:IncrementButton Title="test title" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Design.PreviewWith>
 
  <ControlTheme x:Key="{x:Type controls:IncrementButton}" TargetType="controls:IncrementButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="auto,auto">
          <Grid.Styles>
            <Style Selector="TextBlock">
              <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
            <Style Selector="TextBlock.Title">
              <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
              <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#A45E0E"/>
              <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 10 0 10"/>
            </Style>
            <Style Selector="Button#Increment_btn">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#6798DA"/>
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#6798DA"/>
              <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
              <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20 10"/>
              <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 20 0"/>
              <Style Selector="^:pointerover /template/ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#6798DA"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#6798DA"/>
              </Style>
            </Style>
          </Grid.Styles>
          
          <TextBlock Classes="Title" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" />
          <StackPanel  Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 0 0 10">
            <Button Name="Increment_btn" Content="increment"  />
            <TextBlock Text="count:"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Count}"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter>
  </ControlTheme>
</ResourceDictionary>

add this control to your application in App.axaml
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceInclude Source="/Controls/IncrementButton.axaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

how to use
<StackPanel>
  <controls:IncrementButton Title="My Title" Count="1" />
  <controls:IncrementButton Title="Hello World" Count="2" />
  <controls:IncrementButton Title="bla bla" Count="-5" />
</StackPanel>

result

